# Hiperligações para páginas noutra língua

Tags: debate, hyperlinks

Dada a linguagem oficial do "stackoverflow em Português" ser obviamente o português, devemos também considerar nas nossas respostas e comentários páginas noutras línguas, nomeadamente o inglês que é uma espécie de *lingua franca*? Gostaria de debater este tema, dado que eu próprio ainda não tenho uma resposta definida.

Comment: Minha humilde opinião: as respostas tem que ser autosuficientes, antes de mais nada. Desde que elas sejam, eu entendo que colocar uma referência externa é um complemento (entre deixar sem nada e por um link para um documento em inglês, melhor o link). Agora, é claro que se a referência existir em português, é preferível, para atingir um número maior de usuários.

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/883/citando-conteudo-em-ingles

Comment: @utluiz Obrigado pela ligação.

Answer (score 8):

Na minha opinião links para conteúdos em Inglês são bem-vindos em alguns casos específicos:

- Manual ou documentação original, ou seja, fonte primária de informação
- Sites de referência confiáveis e reconhecidos mundialmente
- Não há referências em Português
- Como sugestão de aprofundamento no assunto
- Há trechos de código interessantes que podem ser usados independentemente do texto

Em todos os casos a resposta aqui no Stack Overflow em Português não deve depender do conteúdo desses links para ser compreensível e útil, mas talvez usá-los como suporte ou base de sustentação.

Comment: Tenho visto alguns casos que não cumprem esses critérios.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo Não posso falar por todos os casos, mas algumas vezes é recomendável adicionar um comentário para o autor da resposta solicitando que ele explique melhor ou adicione mais informações do link citado. Se a resposta for *somente* o link, sinalize para os moderadores que ela pode ser convertida em comentário na pergunta. Se achar que a resposta é ruim, pode votar contra também.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo Você teria um exemplo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, poderei colocar alguns exemplos se os voltar a encontrar.